# How do I write a program that creates new shared queries for a team project in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

> Is it possible using the TFS client object model to create new shared
>   queries for the team project?
>
> If so can you provide a code sample or a link to the MSDN
>   documentation?

We keep a couple queries for each team member and when someone joins then team we have to create new ones for the new member. It doesn't take long, but I'd like to just write a quick program that copies a template query definition, changes the name of the developer, and saves a copy of it. It would be especially useful when we decide to add a column to the query. Currently I have to manually modify 20+ queries definitions. I couldn't find anything on MSDN, but I'm hoping I just missed it somehow.

Comment: Code samples are available at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/06/16/work-item-tracking-queries-object-model-in-2010.aspx

Comment: And examples of WIQL are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm already familiar with WIQL just not the QueryDefinition and QueryHierarchy classes. If you want to move that comment to an answer I'll mark it as correct.